# Insert characters into a string using R

Tags: r

I would like to insert a colon characters once, twice or three times in a string. For example I want

```
G*2413 => G*24:13
G*15122 => G*15:122
G*010101 => G*01:01:01
G*02010102 => G*02:01:01:02
```

How can I do this using R?

```
have <- c('G*2413', 'G*15122', 'G*010101', 'G*02010102')
want <- c('G*24:13', 'G*15:122', 'G*01:01:01', 'G*02:01:01:02')
```

Comment: (`?substring` and `?sprintf`) or (`?regepxr` and (`?regmatches` or `?paste`)). Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also use a positive lookaround

```
gsub("(\\d{2})(?=\\d{2})", "\\1:", have, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "G*24:13"       "G*15:122"      "G*01:01:01"    "G*02:01:01:02"
```

Comment: Can this command be expanded to also include insertion of a colon after 3 digits for a particular data? A have a pre-defined set of data values where I know a colon should be inserted after digit three. I wondered if a IF command could be included.

Comment: @Mona DId you meant `gsub("(\\d{3})(?=\\d{2})", "\\1:", have, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try `(\\d{2}(?!\\d?$))` with `gsub`, replace every two digits with itself followed by a colon character except it is followed by the end of string or followed by one digit at the end of string. `?!` is the negative look ahead syntax which makes sure the pattern to be matched is not followed by another pattern:

```
gsub("(\\d{2}(?!\\d?$))", "\\1:", "G*02010102", perl=T)
# [1] "G*02:01:01:02"

gsub("(\\d{2}(?!\\d?$))", "\\1:", "G*010101", perl=T)
# [1] "G*01:01:01"

gsub("(\\d{2}(?!\\d?$))", "\\1:", "G*15122", perl=T)
# [1] "G*15:122"

gsub("(\\d{2}(?!\\d?$))", "\\1:", "G*2413", perl=T)
# [1] "G*24:13"
```